# Disable vertical border on when website is resized to mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border

So I have this thing as a footer but I want the vertical lines to dissapear when the screen gets lesss than 740px in screen size. Maybe media rule. When I resize to mobile screen the vertical lines are still there messing up my design and I need a code that disables them for screen with widht res less than 740px.

```
 <div id="footer1" >
<div class="container">
  <div id="big-footer1" class="row">

    <div class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3 alpha">

    </div>

    <div class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3">





    </div>       

    <div id="social-icons" class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3 omega">

    </div>


  </div>   


#big-footer1 { 
border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.footer-top-border }}; 
 margin-bottom: 20px; 
 margin-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.footer-bottom-border }}; 
 padding: 30px 0 30px; 
 list-style-type: none; 
 }

 #big-footer1 .alpha { border-right: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
 #big-footer1 .omega { border-left: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }

 #big-footer1 { color: {{ settings.footer-text-color }}; }
 #big-footer1 a { color: {{ settings.footer-text-color }}; }

 #big-footer1 h4 {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 color: {{ settings.footer-header-color }}; 
 display: block;
 text-transform: uppercase; 
}

 #big-footer1 > div { padding: 0 20px; min-height: 120px;}


 #big-footer1 ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 34px;
}

#big-footer1 ul li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px; }

#footer1 { background: {{ settings.footer-background }}; padding-bottom: 20px; text-      align: center; }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply using a media query?

Comment: I have added this but still does not work.

@media handheld {
  #big-footer1 .alpha { border-right: 0px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
#big-footer1 .omega { border-left: 0px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
}

Comment: That's a media *type*. You need to to query a media *feature* (like `max-width`), and I wouldn't use `handheld`, just stick with `screen`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This use case can be handled by media queries. Yours seems like it would need max-width:

```
foo {
    /* Normal styles */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
    foo {
        /* Styles for under 740px */
    }
}
```

See http://jsbin.com/bugay/1/. Resize to see how it works.

More about media queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Glad you found it useful.